# Context dependent split of a string in python

Tags: python, regex, string

Apologies if this is redundant, but a fairly deep search of the intertubes revealed nothing relevant here.

I have a string from a (chemical) database where the separators (commas) are occasionally in the items I am hoping to split.  An example string is

```
s = '2-Methyl-3-phythyl-1,4-naphthochinon,Vitamin, K1,Antihemorrhagic vitamin'
```

The correct split in this instance would yield

```
splitS = ['2-Methyl-3-phythyl-1,4-naphthochinon', 'Vitamin, K1', 'Antihemorrhagic vitamin']
```

I believe that the most accurate way I can design this would be to split on commas which do not have a whitespace next to the comma, and which further are not surrounded by 2 numbers.  This would leave instances such as '1,4' and 'Vitamin, K1', but split the string into the correct 3 chemical names.

I have tried using RE unsuccessfully.  I can post some of what I have tried, but it is pretty much useless.  Help is much appreciated.

EDIT: Should have included this originally.  Through some of my hacking, and from the more elegant solution from @Borealid, I have correctly identified the locations for splitting, but get hideous output such as

```
>>> s = '2-Methyl-3-phythyl-1,4-naphthochinon,Vitamin, K1,Antihemorrhagic vitamin'
>>> pat = re.compile("([^\d\s],[^\d\s])|([^\s],[^\d\s])|([^\d\s],[^\s])")
>>> re.split(pat, s)
['2-Methyl-3-phythyl-1,4-naphthochino', 'n,V', None, None, 'itamin, K', None, '1,A', None, 'ntihemorrhagic vitamin']
```

It seems as though there should be a way to first identify the correct commas to split on, then split on the comma *only*, thus avoiding names being corrupted.

Thanks Again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get this behavior by using [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) so that you only match commas that fit your explanation:

```
(?<!\d),(?! )|(?<=\d),(?![\d ])
```

And it seems to have the correct behavior for you example string:

```
>>> re.split(r'(?<!\d),(?! )|(?<=\d),(?![\d ])', s)
['2-Methyl-3-phythyl-1,4-naphthochinon', 'Vitamin, K1', 'Antihemorrhagic vitamin']
```

Here is the explanation:

```
 (?<!\d),   # match a comma that is not preceeded by a digit...
 (?! )      # ... as long as it is not followed by a space
|           # OR
 (?<=\d),   # match a comma that is preceeded by a digit...
 (?![\d ])  # ... as long as it is not followed by a digit or a space
```

After writing the explanation I've realized that the `(?<=\d)` portion of the regex is unnecessary as it is sort of implied by the first portion of the regex not matching, this means you could shorten it to the following and get the same behavior:

```
(?<!\d),(?! )|,(?![\d ])
```

Comment: Sure does work - thanks!  Now, to spend the rest of the day figuring out why it works... :)

Comment: @theFuriousNoob - See my edit, I added some explanation that should help.

Comment: - Just to check my understanding:  The (?<! and (?! are the negative lookbehind and lookahead, (?<= and (?= are the positive lookbehind and lookahead?  Also, it seems as though a ' ' is identical to \s - why did you choose to put the space vs. the \s?  Any reason I may be missing (other than \s accounting for more than just spaces)? Thanks again!

Comment: `\s` will match spaces, tabs, and newlines.  I just used the space character because it seems like you would still want to split on `',<tab>...'` and `',<newline>...'`, but if that is not the case you could replace the space characters with `\s` or `[ \t]`.  And yes, you have the correct lookaround syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Something like `([^\d\s],[^\d\s])|([^\s],[^\d\s])|([^\d\s],[^\s])`?

Comma with ((Number on neither side) or (number on tail side but not on head side) or (number on head side but not tail side))".

In all cases, no spaces next to the comma.

`\d` is "digit". `\s` is "whitespace". `[]` is a character class - `[^]` is an inverted character class ("match a character which is not in the subsequent contents")

Doesn't split on commas in the very first or very last position of the string, but I don't think that'll be a concern.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution but is a little bit long. Ok, here we go:

```
s = '2-Methyl-3-phythyl-1,4-naphthochinon,Vitamin, K1,Antihemorrhagic vitamin'
```

First, let's find all the positions of the all commas in the string (in `all_commas`) and the positions from all the special commas (in `special_commas`):

```
all_commas = [match.start() for match in re.finditer(r',', s)]
special_commas = [match.start()+1 for match in re.finditer(r'\d,\d|.,\s', s)]
```

Second, we get the difference from those positions (in `split_commas`). Now, we have the positions where we're going to split:

```
split_commas = set(all_commas) - set(special_commas)
```

Then, we are going to iterate over those split positions and save the splited strings in `splitS`

```
splitS = []
start = -1
for end in sorted(split_commas) + [None]:
    splitS.append(s[start+1:end])
    start = end
```

Finally, that's what we get in `splitS`:

```
>>> splitS
['2-Methyl-3-phythyl-1,4-naphthochinon', 'Vitamin, K1', 'Antihemorrhagic vitamin']
```